# Upload file name in database with rename in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to insert file name in database in php. And file will move to CV folder. I used a function to reneme that file.It does not work .

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" required>
    <input type="submit" name="job_post" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    function getFileName($file)
    {
      return date('mdhms'). '.' . $file->extension();
    }
  $f_name= $_POST['file'];
  $filename = getFileName($f_name);
  move(base_path('cv'), $filename); 
  $job_post_sql="INSERT INTO applications (cv,flag) VALUES ('$filename','1')";
  $job_post_sql_result=mysqli_query($con,$job_post_sql);
}
```

Comment: Use php functions move_uploaded_file() and the $_FILES Variable. This link will help you: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` to get name of uploaded file.

```
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Then you can rename file name:

```
$filename = date('mdhms').$name;
```

To move the file to your folder:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $folder);
```

Comment: $folder="cv/";
     move_uploaded_file($folder.$file);
Can I use This?

Comment: @MujahidurRahmanMithunIUB Check the updated answer

Comment: Sorry for late. If I want to up hole file(docx/pdf) into database not file name. Then what need to do?